# How do I get the date AND TIME to show up in a Crystal report?

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports-2010

I'm working with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.  The data is in a SQL Server 2005 database.  The field is a datetime field, within the database/table.  It has both date and time in it.  But my report refuses to see that field as anything other than a date field.  Huh???  According to [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DateFormatInCR06132007092248AM/DateFormatInCR.aspx) on C# Corner, there should be a Date, a Time and a Date And Time tab when customizing the display.  No there isn't; the only data type tab I see, when I try to customize it, is Date.

So, how do I get the date and time to show up from a datetime field returned by the stored procedure, when CR for VS 2010 only wants to treat it as a Date field???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally found the solution.  The report I'm working with is really old.  It was started by someone over 10 years ago, using who knows what version of Crystal Reports was around then.  My colleague decided to start a whole new report and drag the field first from the table, and then from the stored procedure that's used for the report, onto the new report.  Well, the data type was now DateTime!  The best we can figure is the original .rpt file must not have had a DateTime data type (that field in the table has been a DateTime for 15+ years).  We even discovered that creating a new report based upon this existing report, doesn't resolve the issue; it still sees the field as a Date data type only.  So we've got to create a new report and start over from stratch.  Frankly, pretty awful to do, just for 1 field in the report, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

This shows you how to set CR to set how it interprets `DateTime` as either `Date` or `DateTime`:

[SAP Community Network Issue](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1386314)

Comment: Consider quoting relevant parts of the link.